# Minimizing the free energy

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$
Let $H$ be a self-adjoint matrix and define the **free energy** as
$$
F(\Gamma)=\tr(H\Gamma+\Gamma \log \Gamma +(1-\Gamma) \log(1-\Gamma))
$$
where $\Gamma$ satisfies $0\le \Gamma \le 1$. I have seen physics papers suggest that $F(\Gamma)$ is minimized if we take
$$
\Gamma =\frac{1}{e^H +1}
$$
but I can't think of a rigorous proof.

**EDIT**. The "usual" non-rigrous method of proof would be to use variational method, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\delta F &=\tr\left(H\delta\Gamma+\log\left(\frac{\Gamma}{1-\Gamma}\right)\delta\Gamma \right)\\
0&=H+\log\left(\frac{\Gamma}{1-\Gamma}\right)\\
\Gamma &= \frac{1}{e^H+1} 
\end{align}
How would one make this argument rigorous?

**EDIT 2**. I just realized that $F(\Gamma)$ is convex, so I think that the above calculation is **almost** rigorous, except that $\delta\Gamma$ may not commute with $\Gamma$, as pointed out by @Sangchul Lee.

**EDIT 3**. Thank you @Sangchul Lee for the proof. I think I also found another proof, that may be a little more straightforward.

Let $\Gamma_0=1/(e^H+1)$ and let $0\le \Gamma_1 \le 1$. Let $\Gamma(t)=(1-t)\Gamma_0 +t\Gamma_1 =\Gamma_0 +t\Delta$ where $\Delta = \Gamma_1-\Gamma_0$. Let $f(x)=x \log x +(1-x) \log (1-x)$. Hence,
$$
F(\Gamma)-F(\Gamma_0) = \tr(tH\Delta)+\tr (f(\Gamma)-f(\Gamma_0))
$$
Since $f$ is convex, we can apply [Klein's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Klein%27s_inequality) and see that
$$
F(\Gamma)-F(\Gamma_0) \ge \tr(t\Delta (H+\log\Gamma_0 -\log (1-\Gamma_0))=0
$$
Also since $f$ is strictly convex, we see that $\Gamma_0$ is the unique global min.

**By the way**, not sure why this question was voted to close. Please vote to reopen if you think otherwise.

**EDIT 4**. After further looking into the proof of Klein's inequality, there is a subtle "problem" of taking the derivative of a trace function (which is not fully explained in the wikipedia article). @Sangchul Lee deals with this explicitly for this particular case, but I would like to think that it should be able to be done more generally. Hence, I posted another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917770/derivative-of-trace-function).

Comment: By $0 \le \Gamma \le 1$, do you mean entrywise or that all the eigenvalues are between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I mean eigenvalues

Comment: So you calculated the _gradient_ of $F$ and then solved for the value of $\Gamma$ which makes the gradient equal to zero.  Why is that not rigorous enough?

Comment: This result for $\delta F$ seems correct, but how we derive it is rather non-trivial if we allow $\delta\Gamma$ not to commute with $\Gamma$.

Comment: @SangchulLee  The trace operation fixes the commutivity issue, so the derivation is  as trivial as it appears.

Comment: @greg, Noncommutativity affects the computation in a more subtle way, but I agree that the trace partially takes cares of this issue.

Comment: @SangchulLee I don't understand, since ${\rm Tr}(\Gamma\,d\Gamma) = {\rm Tr}(d\Gamma\,\Gamma)$, via the cyclic property of the trace, where exactly is the issue?

Comment: @greg, As you may see from my answer, the real issue stems from the differentiation part.

Comment: @AndrewYuan, Now I see that my solution is essentially reproducing Klein's inequality. Glad to know that a whole area of trace inequalities exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, we will write

$$ D^+_{B}F(A) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{F(A+\epsilon B) - F(A)}{\epsilon} $$

whenever the limit exists. Then the following lemma will be useful:

> **Lemma.** We have
> $$ D^+_{B}\exp(A) = \int_{0}^{1} e^{sA}Be^{(1-s)A} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

*Proof.* We have

$$ D^+_{B}\exp(A)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} D^+_{B}(A^n)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^k B A^{n-1-k}
= \sum_{k,l\geq 0} \frac{A^k B A^l}{(k+l+1)!}. $$

Then the claim follows from the beta integral $\int_{0}^{1} u^k(1-u)^l \, \mathrm{d}s = \frac{k!l!}{(k+l+1)!} $. $\square$

Now let $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ be self-adjoint matrices such that $0 \leq \Gamma_k \leq 1$ for $k = 0, 1$. Interpolate $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ by letting

$$ \Gamma_t = (1-t)\Gamma_0 + t\Gamma_1, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1. $$

We also write $\Delta = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \Gamma_t = \Gamma_1 - \Gamma_0$ since this will appear frequently. Then by the Frullani's integral and the functional calculus,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \log \Gamma_{t}
&=  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} - e^{-x\Gamma_t}}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} (D^+_{\Delta}\exp)(-x\Gamma_t) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-sx\Gamma_t}\Delta e^{-(1-s)x\Gamma_t} \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

From this, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}\left( \Gamma_t \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \log\Gamma_t \right)
&= \operatorname{Tr}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \Gamma_t e^{-sx\Gamma_t}\Delta e^{-(1-s)x\Gamma_t} \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{Tr}\left( \Gamma_t e^{-sx\Gamma_t}\Delta e^{-(1-s)x\Gamma_t} \right) \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{Tr}\left( \Gamma_t e^{-x\Gamma_t}\Delta \right) \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(\Delta),
\end{align*}

and similarly

$$ \operatorname{Tr}\left( (1-\Gamma_t) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \log(1-\Gamma_t) \right) = -\operatorname{Tr}(\Delta). $$

So we obtain

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} F(\Gamma_t)
= \operatorname{Tr}\left( H\Delta + \Delta\log(\Gamma_t) - \Delta\log(1-\Gamma_t) \right) \tag{1} $$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ again,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} F(\Gamma_t)
&= \operatorname{Tr}\left(\Delta \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\log(\Gamma_t) - \Delta \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\log(1-\Gamma_t) \right) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \Delta e^{-sx\Gamma_t}\Delta e^{-(1-s)x\Gamma_t} \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&\qquad + \operatorname{Tr}\left( 
 \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \Delta e^{-sx(1-\Gamma_t)}\Delta e^{-(1-s)x(1-\Gamma_t)} \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \left\| e^{-\frac{1}{2}sx\Gamma_t}\Delta e^{-\frac{1}{2}(1-s)x\Gamma_t} \right\|^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \\
&\qquad + \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \left\| e^{-\frac{1}{2}sx(1-\Gamma_t)}\Delta e^{-\frac{1}{2}(1-s)x(1-\Gamma_t)} \right\|^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \tag{2}
\end{align*}

where $\| X \|^2 = \operatorname{Tr}(X^* X)$ is always a non-negative real number.

Now we are ready to prove the claim.

- From $\text{(2)}$, we know that $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} F(\Gamma_t) \geq 0$, which in turn implies that $F$ is convex.
- $\text{(1)}$ can be used to show that $\Gamma_{\text{m}} = \frac{1}{e^H + 1}$ is a local extremum of $F$. Then by the convexity, this is a local minimum of $F$.

Therefore $\Gamma_{\text{m}}$ minimizes $F$.