# Matrix function derivative with respect to matrix elements

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, tensors

Is there a general procedure to take the derivative of an [analytic function of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix) $f(\mathbf{X}) : \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ (not the element-wise application of a function, but the matrix function defined with the Taylor series or other equivalent means), with respect to each element of the matrix argument?

Comment: Not really. Other than expanding $f(X+H)-f(X)$ and looking for linear terms.

Comment: Since the output is also a matrix, I would write $\mathbf{F} (\mathbf{X})$.

Comment: The usual convention is to use the lowercase

Comment: Lowercase for scalar fields.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It is conventional to use lowercase here since this is the extension of a scalar function to square matrix inputs (or more generally, linear operators in functional calculus).  The wikipedia article linked in the OP is replete with references to $f(A)$, and this seems entirely reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To illustrate what can happen,  suppose we take the very innocent looking function
$$
  F(X)=X^n,
  $$
where $n$ is a positive integer.
Then
$$
  F'(X)(H) =
  \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t = 0}(X+tH)^n  =  $$$$ =
  HX^{n-1} + XHX^{n-2} + X^2HX^{n-3} + \cdots  + X^{n-2}HX + X^{n-1}H =   $$$$ =
  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}   X^kHX^{n-1-k}.
  $$

In other words,  the fact that  matrix multiplication is non-commutative  substantially complicates things.  On the other
hand, when we are differentiating a function of the form
$$
  F(X) = \text{tr}(f(X)),
  $$
things work much better since the trace makes up for the lack of commutativity.  See
[Derivative of trace function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917770/derivative-of-trace-function/3921226#3921226).

Answer (score 3):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\R#1{\in{\mathbb R}^{#1}}$Coordinate-wise derivatives are a useful approach which avoids higher-order tensors or transformations (i.e. vectorization) which flatten those tensors into matrices.

First, given the matrix variable $X\R{n\times n}\,$ its coordinate-wise derivatives are
$$\eqalign{
\p{X}{X_{ij}} &= e_i e_j^T \;\doteq\; E_{ij} \\
}$$
where $e_i$ is a cartesian basis vector and $E_{ij}$ is the single-entry matrix.

Second, given a function defined by the Taylor series
$$F = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k X^k$$
then, assuming the series converges for the given $X,\,$ its coordinate-wise derivatives are
$$\p{F}{X_{ij}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k \left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{k} X^{k-\ell}E_{ij}X^{\ell-1}\right)$$